# Getting ancestors from oracle sql table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CHILD_ID | PARENT_ID
```

Both columns are integers.

I am trying to get all ancestors for a given 'node'. I have the top most id and I would like to select a table containing all the ids of the children.

```
CHILD_ID | PARENT_ID
1          2
6          12
2          3
3          4
9          82
```

Finding the ancestors for `4`

Should return

```
ID
3
2
1
```

How would this be done in oracle?

Can it be done without a stored procedure?

As always, thank you in advanced for your time.

Comment: That would be the descendants, not the ancestors.

Comment: You're right that should be. Unfortunately that's how it's named in the data model that I am working with. Can't change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To meet your output expectations, the query could be like this:

```
-- sample of data
SQL> with t1(CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID) as(
  2    select 1,  2  from dual union all
  3    select 6,  12 from dual union all
  4    select 2,  3  from dual union all
  5    select 3,  4  from dual union all
  6    select 9,  82 from dual
  7  ) -- actual query
  8  select child_id
  9    from t1
 10  start with parent_id = 4
 11  connect by parent_id = prior child_id
 12  ;

  CHILD_ID
----------
         3
         2
         1
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without hard coding values? I will do some more research on common table expressions.

Comment: @chrisg32 Those "hard coded" values you see in the `with` clause are there just for the sake of demonstration(in order to not create a table and populate it with data we can can use `with` clause). Actual query starts at line 8. So take the query, replace `t1` with your table name and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks  @NicholasKrasnov, I realized that as soon as I submitted the comment. Right now I am just waiting on our DBA to do something then I will give it a try.

Comment: beware of connect by loop error, depending on the data.  You may need CONNECT BY NOCYCLE

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to do either adjacency trees or nested set trees. Then you can do super fast operations that return subtrees from a single query. The worst solution would be to take a cursor and step through the records and try and recurse through each record's parents.

Nested set trees are amazing, the only downside to them is that they need to be renumbered when they've been changed. But if you need to compute aggregates, for example, their speed is completely bananas.

[Wikipedia on the Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)
[Joe Celko's Explanation (excellent)](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html)